# Get time from LocalDateTime

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime

I'm looking to get the time from LocalDateTime (unless there is an easier way) with the format of HH:mm:a (12:34 pm)
Which Date/Time formatter do I want to use?

```
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:a")
val dt = LocalDateTime.now().format(sdf)
print("Time: $dt")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just managed to accomplish that the other way. Look at my code bellow.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

fun main() {
    val sdf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:a")
    val dt = LocalDateTime.now().format(sdf)
    println("Time: $dt")
}
```

Reference:

[Kotlin Program to Get Current Date/Time](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/examples/current-date-time)

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

(Using Java syntax.)

```
myLocalDateTime
.toLocalTime()  // Extract the time only, without the date portion.
.format(        // Automatically localize.
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT )
    .withLocale( Locale.US )
)
```

## Details

The [Answer by Luiz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70726857/642706) is correct. I can show a couple of alternatives: extracting the time only, and automatically localizing.

If you want to focus on the time of day, extract a `LocalTime` object.

```
LocalTime lt = myLocalDateTime.toLocalTime() ;
```

Rather than hard-code a specific format, it is generally best to let *java.time* automatically localize.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.US ) ;
String output = lt.format( f ) ;
```